# iptables performance during high-pps UDP attack

Tags: networking, iptables, ddos

One of my servers is under constant UDP DDOS attack. ~500Mb/s and 700k PPS. I have a 10Gbit downlink so that is not the bottleneck.

In my IPTABLES I have created a 'whitelist' via ipset and dropping all other traffic that tries to reach my game server.

The ipset set has ~2000 IP addresses and 10 CIDR rows in it. Type of set: netash

Table: **RAW**

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set allowip src
DROP       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            135.x.x.x            udp dpt:30120
```

This **worked very well** until the PPS of the attacks started in increase.

While the server is still up and not lagging, IPTABLES seems to have a hard time processing the whitelisted IP's among this high packet count during the attack. 50% of the players are getting connection issues in-game even when their IP is whitelisted in the allowip ipset list. CPU usage is also not crazy high.

Is this some kind of limitation of the max PPS in iptables? Or can I do something to speed up?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add, for completeness: which type of the set and how many addresses in it?

Comment: ipset create allowip nethash, 

1900 IP addresses in this set. I'm btw dropping the packets in the RAW PREROUTING table/chain.

Comment: Do you have an unusually large amount of _legitimate_ traffic from any of those networks? If so, it may be helpful to place those in a separate ipset that is checked first.

Comment: No all players use about the same amount of traffic.

Comment: You could do benchmarks compared to nftables + a set. nftables can hook to a NIC in the netdev family  which happens earlier in the packet's life than iptables' raw, so maybe you get less overhead in the end.